# Текст поверх ImageView

Tags: java, android, xml

Пытаюсь разместить текст поверх картинки, но ничего не выходит. вот код

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/list_background"
        >
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/t_c"
              android:textColor="@color/text8"
              android:text="yyy"
              android:textSize="25dp"
              android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView3"/>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/t_st"
              android:textColor="@color/name"
              android:textSize="25dp"
              android:text="rrrr"
              android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            />
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/h_o"
              android:textColor="@color/list_divider"
              android:text="rrrr"
              android:textSize="25dp"
              android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:background="@drawable/c_b"
               android:id="@+id/imageView3"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если под "ничего не выходит" имеется в виду, что текст отображается под картинкой, а не над, то попробуйте переместить объявление **ImageView** в начало списка детей **RelativeLayout**. Таким образом **ImageView** должен быть в самом низу иерархии и все **TextView** должны будут отображаться поверх **ImageView**.